# Filtered HTML does not work in field

Tags: entities

I have a field and set its input format to *Filtered HTML*. Its content some text within the `<strong>` and `</strong>`, which are allowed by the input format I chose.

However, when displaying the a node of that content type, the text is still displayed as plain text and the `<strong>` tag seems to be ignored.

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: permissions for `filtered_html`. Display settings for content type

Comment: At the page, where I display the field, I had to configure the field again. And change the `formatter` to `Default`. Does this make sense?

Comment: I can't follow. Could you explain what are you doing?

Comment: I already resolved my issue: Beside setting "filtered html" in the field config, I also had to change the "formatter" when actually displaying the field on a page. Therefore I had to edit the "view" and there change the field's "formatter" to "default". that resolved my issue.

Comment: Your first comment above is also correct. I needed it just now when displaying the field on the actual content type.

Comment: so I am 10 Points here shorter;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **config >> content >> formats >> filtered_html**

In bottom have **Filter setting** choose **Limit allowed HTML tags** add in it allowed HTML tags

[image]

Comment: <strong> is already in this list by default.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to share with the global settings for the input format, since each fields have specific settings for the input format it uses.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a field as you did, and it worked perfectly, for me.

> [image: screenshot]

The only way I could make the field not displayed with the allowed tags I used for its content was to set the format of that field to *Plain text* (on admin/structure/types/manage/page/display, where page is the content type to which I added the field).

> [image: screenshot]

Drupal should use the default format, as it happened with me. I cannot tell you why it used the *Plain text* format in your case, since I cannot reproduce this for a field I create ex-novo.